# Can't assign to a <T extends INode> typed variable an INode type value. Why?

Tags: java, generics

I'm wondering why the following code fails to work:

```
public static <T extends INode> List<T> cloneList(List<T> list) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(list.size());

    for (T t : list)
        result.add(t.clone()); <--- problem here

    return result;
}
```

`INode.clone()` has `INode` return type, and we know that every T must implement `INode`, so I'm surprised the above code doesn't compile. Is there any semantic problem with what I'm showing above?

EDIT: Maybe because at compile time Java will erase the generic type and a cast is then still needed? Couldn't the compiler have done that for me?

EDIT2: Here's `INode`:

```
public interface INode {
    INode accept(Visitor visitor);
    INode clone();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T is an INode but INode is not a T.
So you can't put the result of INode.clone() (Object or Inode) into a list of T.
That's why you need a cast

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First, I suppose that INode is an interface, so the clone() method shouldn't be available directly because it is defined in Object. You should define a clone() method in the interface or make INode extend Cloneable then cast the cloned Node to T.

Furthermore, you as I wrote, you need to cast your cloned object to T because you know that both T and the clone are instances of INode but you are not sure that the clone is an instance of T.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suspect you haven't re-declare the `clone` method in `INode` class and implements interface `Cloneable`.

Besides, a cast to `T` is required in order to insert the clone into parameterized list.