# What if I implement List and call add in a method that accepts List<? extends SuperType>

Tags: java, generics

I have read that the following code snippet will result in a [compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495383/java-generics-wildcard-question-list-extends-a)

```
void tryAddingToList(List<? extends SuperType> list) {
  list.add(new SubType());
}
```

Now my question is:
 Who exactly sets the restriction and how is the restriction set? Does the compiler specifically check for the `add` method call in such a method implementation?

If yes, what if I implement my own `List` and instead of `add`, introduce a new `addToList` method that does the same thing as `add`, and call that in the `tryAddingToList` method?

Even better, what if I implement my `get` method such that it also "secretly" adds something to the list (don't ask me why anyone would do that; I'm just curious).

Comment: The compiler won't let you add to a list which has a bounded wildcard. That's a rule. As for your second question, will your own List implementation be parameterized or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `super` instead of `extends` here.

```
void tryAddingToList(List<? super SubType> list) {
    list.add(new SubType());
}
```

Assume there are 3 types `SuperType`, `SubType1`, `SubType2`. In your original code, `List<? extends SuperType>` could be `List<SubType2>`, and you can't add a `SubType1` to `List<SubType2>`.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer my question, which is about how the restriction set by `? extends` is enforced.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast `SubType` to `SuperType` explicitly. Because not all objects of `SuperType` are `SubType`(may be typed other sub-classes). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377225/cant-assign-to-a-t-extends-inode-typed-variable-an-inode-type-value-why/9377462#9377462) may give you some hint. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! But my question isn't about how to make that code snippet work.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. It's also wrong, because `SubType` can always be implicitly cast to `SuperType`: the compile error is because the compiler doesn't know what concrete subclass the generic type refers to.

Comment: This is also a common way to "declare" some collection as read-only. Don't be surprised if you see something like `List<? extends String> foo` - it's just a read-only List of Strings.

Comment: @Jagat You're welcome. Sorry for can't help you more. @Cameron Thanks for pointing the implicit cast out, then is any differences between `void tryAddingToList(List<? extends SuperType> list)` and `void <T extends SuperType> tryAddingToList(List<T> list)` as that declared in another post I referred?

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea There's no difference. T, in your example, is used just to capture the actual type so that you can reuse the actual type in your method. For instance, to create a List<T> for some purpose.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Again, how is it marked read only? How does the compiler know that a method is actually "writing"? Perhaps it knows that `add` in the List interface is a method that modifies the List. But I could always come up with a method that also writes to the List, in my own implementation.

Comment: @Jagat I was only saying that you cannot add to a list declared as `List<? extends Foo>`. [This great wildcards tutorial from Oracle](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) explains this (look up `public void addRectangle(List<? extends Shape> shapes)` there).

Comment: It's not correct to think of List<? extends SuperType> as a read only list. You can still add to it nulls, remove elements, sort it, etc. Use Collections.unmodifiableList for this purpose

Comment: @dcernahoschi: Absolutely, this is not the canonical way to declare unmodifiable collections, I was just referring to a trick developers use in APIs to let their users know some collection should not be modified (notice, I quoted the "declare" verb in my comment.)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov ah,ok. I missed the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's indeed the compiler that applies the restriction. Most of the information (not all) will be erased when actually compiled to byte code. You should interpreted generics as extra information for the developer, so we don't make silly mistakes.